# converting color image to gray scale image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am facing a problem with writing and reading a gray scale image in open cv using c++. This is my code to read a color image as gray scale image and to write it in a file:

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread("c:\\users\\selva\\desktop\\newimage.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
cv::imwrite("c:\\users\\selva\\desktop\\grayscal.jpg",source);
```

Then i tried to read that image in a new project,

```
cv::Mat gray = cv::imread("c:\\users\\selva\\desktop\\grayscal.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

But when i execute this code,

`std::cout<<gray.channels();` The output in console is 3.

I am using opencv 2.4.7, i tried with .png format, but that does not help.

console value for  `std::cout<<source.channels();` is 1.

If my `newimage.jpg`  is a gray scale image and i am reading as,

`cv::Mat source = cv::imread("c:\\users\\selva\\desktop\\newimage.jpg",0);`
the problem is same.
I am sure that i am loading correct image.
Please anyone answer why it happens. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try saving as png instead of jpg and load that one?

Comment: @SELVA If you do `std::cout << source.channels()` what do you get?

Comment: Load color images with imread("",1) and grayscale with imread("",0). read the documentation about the [flags](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread).

Comment: What version of OpenCV do you use?

Comment: for me (opencv249 prebuild libs for vc2010) your code works perfectly. Are you sure you load the right image?